# Error with strings

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a new programmer and i've decided to try to learn python 3.4.1 . I decided to try to make a times table testing program. However it has an error in the function "question". The error occurs when I enter the correct integer after entering a string. It handles the strings correctly up until I enter the correct answer. After that python gives out an error. I am confused by this as I don't think those two parts of the code should influence each other.

Could some one please explain to me what I've done wrong and what the right way is to do it? Please help.

Code below:

```
def main():
    global c
    c = 0
    ask_a()
    ask_b()
    print("Type Quit to stop the questions at any time")
    while c < 10:
        question()
    ans = input("Do you want to have another go?")
    if ans in("y","Y","yes","Yes"):
            main()
def question():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    print (str(a) + " x " + str(b+c) + " = ")
    answer = input()
    try:
        int(answer)
    except:
        if answer in ("q","Q","quit","Quit"):
            main()
        else:
            print("Try again!")
            question()
    if int(answer) == a*(b+c):
        print("Correct")
        c +=1
    else:
        print("Try again!")
        question()
def ask_a():
    global a
    a = input("What times tables would you like to do? \n")
    check_a()
def ask_b():
    global b
    b = input("What number would you like to start from? \n")
    check_b()
def check_a():
    global a
    try:
        a = int(a)
    except:
        print("You didn't enter a number...")
        ask_a()
def check_b():
    global b
    try:
        b = int(b)
    except:
        print("You didn't enter a number...")
        ask_b()
main()
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with example input, the **full** output you are getting, including the exact text of any errors or tracebacks, and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: You really should not use `global` that often. Instead, use parameters and `return` to pass values between functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is much going on here, but the proximate cause failure involves (as tobias_k pointed out) recursively calling the question() function from within the exception handler.

To see what's going on, you can insert diagnostic print() functions to report the object id of the variable 'answer' (revised code below) and doing a test run.  In this session, first a wrong answer is provided. Then upon recursion, the correct answer:

```
What times tables would you like to do? 
3
What number would you like to start from? 
4
Type Quit to stop the questions at any time
3 x 4 = 
wrong answer
trying answer: wrong answer id 53796784  in try block
Try again!
3 x 4 = 
12
trying answer: 12 id 53834112  in try block
trying answer: 12 id 53834112  in try block
Correct
trying answer: wrong answer id 53796784  in try block

... resulting in this traceback:

File "c:\xxxx\test.py", line 57, in <module>
  main()
File "c:\xxxx\test.py"", line 8, in main
  question()
File "c:\xxxx\test.py"", line 28, in question
  if int(answer) == a*(b+c):

builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'wrong answer'
```

You'll note that it failed while evaluating the old / incorrect answer (id 53796784) while the user would think that it's evaluating the new / correct one (id 53834112).

Here's your code, intact except for the diagnostic print statements:

```
 def main():
    global c
    c = 0
    ask_a()
    ask_b()
    print("Type Quit to stop the questions at any time")
    while c < 10:
        question()
    ans = input("Do you want to have another go?")
    if ans in("y","Y","yes","Yes"):
            main()
def question():
    global a
    global b
    global c
    print (str(a) + " x " + str(b+c) + " = ")
    answer = input()
    try:
        print('trying answer:', answer, 'id', id(answer), ' in try block')
        int(answer)
    except:
        if answer in ("q","Q","quit","Quit"):
            main()
        else:
            print("Try again!")
            question()
    print('trying answer:', answer, 'id', id(answer), ' in try block')        
    if int(answer) == a*(b+c):
        print("Correct")
        c +=1
    else:
        print("Try again!")
        print('question', id(question))
        question()
def ask_a():
    global a
    a = input("What times tables would you like to do? \n")
    check_a()
def ask_b():
    global b
    b = input("What number would you like to start from? \n")
    check_b()
def check_a():
    global a
    try:
        a = int(a)
    except:
        print("You didn't enter a number...")
        ask_a()
def check_b():
    global b
    try:
        b = int(b)
    except:
        print("You didn't enter a number...")
        ask_b()
main()
```

I agree with tobias_k that you should avoid using global whenever possible.

You can achieve a good deal of encapsulation and clarity by passing important bits of information around as parameters.  Here's an alternative implementation that keeps most of your logical bits intact, while straightening out a few kinks in the road:

You can avoid using try/except blocks altogether here using the built-in string method isdigit(). Cf. below:

```
def check_int(q):
    "keep requesting input until an integer is provided"
    while True:
        test=input(q)
        if test.isdigit():   #quick and dirty integer test
            return int(test)
        else:
            print("You didn't enter a number...")

def check_ans(ans, a, b, c):
    "evaluate answer, return 0 if quit requested"
    if ans.isdigit():
        if int(ans) == a*(b+c):
            print("Correct")
            return 1
    elif ans.lower() not in ('q', 'quit'):
        print("Try again!")
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

a = check_int("What times tables would you like to do? \n")
b = check_int("What number would you like to start from? \n")
c = 0

print("Type Quit to stop the questions at any time")

while True:
    c+=1
    answer =input(str(a) + ' x ' + str(b+c) + ' = ')
    answer_eval = check_ans(answer, a , b, c)
    if c < 10 and answer_eval:
        ans = input("Do you want to have another go? ")
        if not ans.lower() in ('y', 'yes'):
            break
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use resursive call of the `question`. It is possible, but the nature of the problem asks for the `while` loop.

Notice that the recursive `question` is called during the exception handling. It is likely that another exception happens deeper. Together with global variables, it cannot fit in a human brain to design it correctly.

But the source of the problem probably is the following part of the code:

```
try:
    int(answer)
except:
    ...

if int(answer) == ...:
    ...
```

When the `int(answer)` causes the exception in the `try/except` construct, then it will cause the same exception later, after everything was recursively solved in the `except` branch.

My +1 to tobias_k for the second comment below the question. I would be only more strict: As a beginner, never use `global`. You will not use it also as an advanced programmer. It is almost always the sign of bad design.